# Unit test in EF data model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am generated an CRUD operations in entity frame work in mvc4. Now i Unit test that classes ..  i am using the following code in controller for creation

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Member member)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Members.Add(member);
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(member);
}
```

and i am using the test code for testing this is,

```
[TestMethod]
public void Create()
{
    MemberController me = new MemberController();
    var mem = new Member();
    mem.MemID = 123;
    mem.MemName = "sruthy";
    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)me.Create(mem);
    Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```

i am just try to test the create class. but it shows the following error

Test failed: Create

> Message: Test method SmpleTest.MemberTest.Create threw exception:
>   System.data>ProviderIncomactibleException:An error occured while
>   getting provider information from the database. This can be  cased by
>   Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exception for details and ensure that the connection  string is
>   correct.--->System.data.ProviderIncompatibleException:The provide did
>   not return a ProviderManifestToken string.--->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:A network- related or intace
>   specific error occured while establishing a connection to  SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accesable. Varify that the
>   instance name is correct and the SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections.(proider:SQL Network Interfaces, error:26-Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)

This is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SampleDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial      Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Sample.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Normally Create operation is worked with this connection string. Can anybody please help me to identify the problem. Thank you

Comment: FYI: this is not a unit test, it's an integration test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the connection string in test case project and your return action is `Create` not the `Index`.

Comment: i am using only one connection string . that is in my web.Config file

Comment: Your Test case is in seperate Project. So need to add connection string

Comment: that means i need to create a web config file in my test project

Comment: Yes, Create app.config in your test project